# Find values of $x$ and $y$ that maximise the given equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$10x+8y=S$ and $x+y=20$.
$10\le x\le 20$
Find the values of $x$ and $y$ that maximize $S$.

Was practicing maxima and minima when I tweaked the question a little bit to make this problem. 
Help please?

Comment: Are you secure there no requirements such as $20 \geq x \geq 0$ probably?

Comment: Updated with one :D

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $y=20-x$ you get

$$10x+8(20-x)=2x+160=S,$$
so $S$ can be as big as you want, i.e. there is no extremum.

Answer (score 0):

Lovsovs is correct; there is no upper bound.

Another way to think of it is multiplying your second equation by eight, then subtracting it from the original. You will be left with a constant, plus $2x$ equals the sum. As $x$ becomes arbitrarily large, $y$ will be almost equally negative. The $8x+8y$ will essentially balance out, and then two more $x$ will be added, which we determined can be as large as we desire.

Answer (score 0):

With your added constraint on $x$, there is an extremum for $S$, which we can see from looking at Lovsovs's answer. Since we can substitute $y=x-20$ to obtain $$2x+160=S$$ we can see that $S$ will be maximized if we make $x$ as large as possible, which based on our constraint is $x=20$